# Searching for an int inside a file

Tags: c++

So I am supposed to take all ints in source3.txt and check which of them occur in source.txt. If any of them don't occur, I'm supposed to print a corresponding line from source2.txt to output.txt (source2.txt contains descriptions of the numbers in source 3, in the same order, each description is 1 line). I wrote this code, but it only prints the last line from  source2.txt, furthermore it is a wrong line.
I have no idea what might be wrong. Can you help me?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream source ("source.txt");
    ifstream source2 ("source2.txt");
    ifstream source3 ("source3.txt");
    vector<int> tab(1051,0);
    vector<string> tab2(857,*new string);
    vector<int> tab3(857,0);

    ofstream output("output.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<1050;++i)
    {
        source>>tab[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<856;++i)
    {
        string a;
        getline(source2,a);
        tab2[i]=a;
        source3>>tab3[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<856;++i)
    {
        if(std::find(tab.begin(), tab.end(), tab3[i]) != tab.end())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            output<<tab2[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: … why do you include an implementation detail header?

Comment: Remove `,*new string` - you're leaking memory. `0` and the empty string already are the default values in the vectors. If you want to explicitly specify a default string, use `string()`.

Comment: because it is a one run only code and I don't care about efficiency

Comment: First of all, add some error checking to make sure that all files are opened and that you've read everything. Print the vectors to verify their contents.

Comment: @molbdnilo If I/O streams are not opened, compiler won't give any error. So better check for those. Overall code looks fine, should work

Comment: I tested your code. my output matches your expectation. One thing I do notice in your code is that you're allocating 1051 elements for "tab" but only loading 1050 of those. The remaining 1 item is still loaded as 0; and may result in incorrect search hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below modifications to code should work for you . Replace value of SOURCE_COUNT with 1051 and  SOURCE2_COUNT  with 857

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <vector>

const int SOURCE_COUNT = 4;
const int SOURCE2_COUNT = 3;
//const int SOURCE2_COUNT = 3;

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream source ("source.txt");
    ifstream source2 ("source2.txt");
    ifstream source3 ("source3.txt");
    vector<int> tab(SOURCE_COUNT,0);
    vector<string> tab2(SOURCE2_COUNT,"");
    vector<int> tab3(SOURCE2_COUNT,0);

    ofstream output("output.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<SOURCE_COUNT;++i)
    {
        source>>tab[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<SOURCE2_COUNT;++i)
    {
        string a;
        getline(source2,a);
        tab2[i]=a;
        source3>>tab3[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<SOURCE2_COUNT;++i)
    {
        if(std::find(tab.begin(), tab.end(), tab3[i]) != tab.end())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            output<<tab2[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are printing only in those cases where you have **not** found the number. In other words, the cases in your if-statement are reversed. It should read:

```
    if(std::find(tab.begin(), tab.end(), tab3[i]) != tab.end())
        output<<tab2[i]<<endl;
```

[EDIT] Oops, I read the question not carefully enough. It should print the line, if the number is NOT contained in source3. So the loop should read:

```
    if(std::find(tab.begin(), tab.end(), tab3[i]) == tab.end())
        output<<tab2[i]<<endl;
```

Also: I would strongly suggest to do away with all those constants like 856 and 1050. Why don't you simply read the file until you reach the end?

Comment: As the question states: "If any of them don't occur, I'm supposed to print [...]"

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully. Are you certain that source.txt contains any numbers that are not contained in source3? Also: I would run it in the debugger and then you will see what's happening with a minute.